# Drop down list not showing any items from mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, inner-join

As the title says when I am creating a drop down list with my mysqli query in my second form  (attendanceOut.php) I'm not getting any items. I am already pulling some of the info from a previous drop down box in my attendance.php which works correctly as far as I can tell. I'm sure it has to do with the fact that this one is being pulled from an INNER JOIN but I can't find where I've messed up on the syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated. So without further ado some code.

```
 <?php

    $course = $_GET["CourseName"];
    $startTime = $_GET["BeginTime"];
    $course = trim($course);
    $course = strip_tags($course);
    $startTime = trim($startTime);
    $startTime = strip_tags($startTime);
    ?>

    <html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset=utf-8">
    <body>

    <?php

    $mydbconn = new mysqli("www.evilscriptmonkeys.com", "capstone", "capstone","attendance");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    printf("connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    if ($_GET['action'] == 'Create Form')
    {   
    //$result = mysqli_query($mydbconn, "SELECT * FROM student WHERE CourseName = ' " .$course."'");
    $c =$course;
    $s = $startTime;
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM student WHERE CourseName = '$c' AND Time > '$s'");
    $result = $mydbconn->query($sql);
    printf ($course);
    printf ($startTime);
    echo '<table border="1">';

    $classFields = $result->fetch_fields();

    foreach ($classFields as $classData)
    {
        echo "<th> $classData->name </th>";
    }

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($row as $col=>$val)
        {
            echo "<td> $val </td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }

}
?>
<form method = "get" action="changeID.php">
Student Name: <select Name='UserName'>
<option value = "">---Select---</option>
<?php
if ($_GET['action'] == 'Edit Student ID')
{
    $c =$course;
    $result = mysqli_query($mydbconn, "SELECT s2.UserName 
                                       FROM student s1 
                                       INNER JOIN students s2 
                                       ON s1.UserName = s2.UserName 
                                       WHERE s1.CourseName = '$c'");
    while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)))
    {
        echo "<option value=\" " . $row['s2.UserName'] . "\">". $row['s2.UserName'] . "</option>";
    }

}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Change" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$row['s2.UserName']` to `$row['UserName']`

Comment: Thanks that was the problem.

Comment: I'd probably recommend editing out your DB connection details (if those are legit ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alias and then access with it in the array:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['action'] == 'Edit Student ID')
{
    $c =$course;
    $result = mysqli_query($mydbconn, "SELECT s2.UserName AS UserName
                                       FROM student s1 
                                       INNER JOIN students s2 
                                       ON s1.UserName = s2.UserName 
                                       WHERE s1.CourseName = '$c'");
    while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)))
    {
        echo "<option value=\" " . $row['UserName'] . "\">". $row['UserName'] . "</option>";
    }

}
?>
```

Hope this help.